# Feynman's QED 36000 revolutions per inch

Tags: visible-light, quantum-electrodynamics, wavelength

In Feynman's book, QED, on page 27 he says "As long as the photon moves, the stopwatch hand turns (about 36,000 times per inch for red light); when the photon ends up at the photomultiplier, we stop the watch.

There are about 36,000 wavelengths of red light in one inch.   So is he saying that the directions of the little arrows represent the phase angle of the EM oscillations at the point of scattering? Or is it a wave solution for the wave function?  Or what  determines how rapidly the angle of the little arrow da changes with position dx.

Answer (score 1):

Feynman's stopwatch is the phase of a complex number, $e^{i k x}$, where $k=2\pi/\lambda$ is the *wavenumber* and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the wave. One rotation of the complex number occurs when $k x = 2\pi$; $N$ rotations occur when $kx = 2\pi N$.

Therefore, given $\lambda=36000^{-1}\ {\rm inch}$ (or in other words, $36000$ wavelengths per inch), and $x=1\ {\rm inch}$, we can calculate
\begin{equation}
N = \frac{kx}{2\pi} = \frac{x}{\lambda} = \frac{1\ {\rm inch}}{36000^{-1}\ {\rm inch}} = 36000
\end{equation}

Comment: That's the same definition as phase angle.  kx=\theta.   So my question "is it phase", seems to be answered, "yes."    Thank you.